# Защита ячеек от внесения данных без защиты листа VBA Ecxel

Tags: vba

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно защитить определенные ячейки без защиты листа, например при ручной вставке строки,  4 ячейки из этой строки должны быть защищены от форматирования, но при этом должен быть доступ для внесения значений макросом в эти ячейки. И другой вопрос, имеется строка с объединением двух ячеек необходимо вставить новую строку под объединением и заблокировать ячейки самого объединения от случайного внесения строки?

Comment: Разделите, пожалуйста, этот вопрос на два. Спасибо!

Comment: Ну напиши OnChange, который восстанавливает нужный формат...